# How to create a pivot table with a calculated column?

Tags: spotfire

In the original data source, I created a new calculated column (Insert > Calculated Column).

When I go to create a pivot table (Insert > Transformation), the new calculated column does not appear as a field I can select. How do I create a pivot table with this new calculated column that I added? Thanks!

Comment: @JT8592- When you create cross table from a table, all the columns including calculated columns will be considered. Did you add calculated column to the main table after you created cross table? In that case, you have to refresh the cross table, then you will be able to see the new column which you can add.

Comment: Hello, I'm not trying to create a cross table (Insert > Visualization > Cross table). I want to create a transformation table (by going to Insert > Transformation) with this new calculated column but it does not show up there.

Comment: @JT8592- Ok, as far as I understand, you are trying to add PIVOT transformation to your original table which has this calculated column. Is that correct? Also, if you could post some screenshots of the issue, that would be helpful.

Comment: Yes that is correct, I am trying to add a Pivot Transformation to my original table and include the calculated column in the Transformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't doable. The reason is the calculated column is based off the data source and is re-calculated any time the data is refreshed, updated, etc at runtime... that means when the data is loaded from the source, the calculated column is created. Your transformation can't be based off this at runtime. What you can do, is insert a transformation and then create a calculated column **after** the transformation.

Answer (score 0):

If are ok with not editing the created column, you can use option of "Freeze Column". You get this button when you create a new column on bottom right.